# Pyhon - "Unhandled exception in listener callback" with pynput

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd appreciate any help or insights.

This code raises an error:

```
import win32com.client
import clipboard
import pyautogui as pya
import time
from pynput import keyboard

speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.f2:
        speaker.Speak("hi") # <--------- This line
        #print('hi')

listener = keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release)

listener.start()

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

### The error message:

```
Unhandled exception in listener callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\menny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 162, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\menny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 274, in _process
    self.on_release(key)
  File "C:\Users\menny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 78, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "C:\Users\menny\Desktop\test.py", line 12, in on_release
    speaker.Speak("hi")                      ┌────────────────────────────┐
  File "<COMObject SAPI.SpVoice>", line 2, in Speak char to copy up to:   │
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147221008), None)
```

### Additional Info

1. If I replace

```
speaker.Speak("hi")
```

with

```
print('hi')
```

everything works well.

2. If I use

```
speaker.Speak("hi")
```

outside the function, it works well.

3. If I replace

```
speaker.Speak("hi")
```

with other commands (like calling other functions) I receive similar error messages.

Any ideas? (Windows 10, Python 3.8)

Comment: `listener` uses `thread` to run `on_release` and maybe it can be problem.

Comment: It's getting weirder. If I'm adding "speaker.Speak("hi")" before the listener.start() then it fixes the problem (i.e. I can then call "speaker.Speak("hi")" from the listener)

Comment: if you resolved problem then you can put it as answer. Maybe it helps other people.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that would be considered as a valid solution.
Nevertheless, it seems like if I call the

```
speaker.Speak("hi")
```

command before I call the

```
listener.start()
```

command, then I can use the speaker command inside the listener.
Here is the working code:

```
import win32com.client
import clipboard
import pyautogui as pya
import time
from pynput import keyboard

speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.Speak("hi") # <--------- I added this line

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.f2:
        speaker.Speak("hi") 
        #print('hi')

listener = keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release)

listener.start()

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```