# Python pynput - capture keys - unhandled exception in listener callback - main thread is not in main loop

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard-shortcuts, pynput

I have a twin question here where I was trying to bind with TKinter.  But I'm willing to use PYNPUT if that helps me to get my functionality working sooner.

I've studied this [Pyhon - "Unhandled exception in listener callback" with pynput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256003/pyhon-unhandled-exception-in-listener-callback-with-pynput)  and it helped some, but I haven't got past the error.

With PYNPUT, I am able to capture the keys, and branch to a function, but then it goes into threading.py and __init__py and blows up with this:

```
E:\Python\Python36\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition with Anaconda plugin 2019.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 10281 --file E:/GitHub/NealWalters/game/game.py
pydev debugger: process 32480 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 192.7142.79)
verify playerCard1=Queen of Clubs verify playerCard2=Six of Hearts
on_press: key='p'
calling self.play()
Unhandled exception in listener callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 162, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 280, in _process
    self.on_press(key)
  File "E:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 78, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "E:/GitHub/NealWalters/game/game.py", line 117, in on_press
    self.play()
  File "E:/GitHub/NealWalters/game/game.py", line 177, in play
    self.message1.setMsg() # clear
  File "E:\GitHub\NealWalters\game\textboxes.py", line 56, in setMsg
    self.msgLine.undraw( )
  File "E:\GitHub\NealWalters\game\graphics.py", line 68, in undraw
    self.canvas.delete(self.id)
  File "E:\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2508, in delete
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'delete') + args)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

It actually dies on self.canvas.delete(self.id) below.  When not running PYNPUT/listener, everything works fine if I click on the buttons.

```
def undraw(self):
    if not self.canvas: return
    self.canvas.delete(self.id)
    self.canvas = None
    self.id = None
```

At this time, there is no user input in this game other than the user clicking buttons. I want to capture the key strokes and call the same method that would have been called had the user pressed the button.

With the Debugger on, I see that I'm getting my key, then callin the "play" function.  It never makes it to the second line of the play function.

This is a game I got from GitHub, and adapting to my preferences. So I'm trying to change it as little as possibly structurally.

The main program is basically something like this:

```
def main():
    # first number is width, second is height
    screenWidth = 800
    screenHeight = 500
    mainWindow = GraphWin("Game", screenWidth, screenHeight)
    game = game(mainWindow)
    listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=game.on_press)
    listener.start()
    game.go()
    mainWindow.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I added a test function in the Game class, and it currently is not firing.

```
def on_press(self, key):
    print("on_press: key=" + str(key))
    if key == keyboard.KeyCode(char='p'):
        print("calling self.play()")
        self.play()

def play( self , event=''):
    """ User pressed the Play button. """
    self.message1.setMsg() # 
    self.message2.setMsg() # <--- I never reach here!
```

message1 and 2 are defined in the game constructor:

```
    self.message1 = MessageBox(win, Point(xmax*0.55, m1y))
    self.message2 = MessageBox(win, Point(xmax*0.55, m2y))
```

And finally, the MessageBox code is in textboxes.py:

```
class MessageBox:
    "Just a Text area to display a message in"
    def __init__( self, win, center ):
        self.win = win
        self.center = center
        self.set = False

    def setMsg( self, msg=None ):
        """Show a message, call with no parameters to
        remove the score from the screen"""
        if msg:
            self.msgLine = Text( self.center, msg )
            self.msgLine.setFill("gold")
            #self.msgLine.setSize( 12 )
            #self.msgLine.setStyle( "bold" )
            self.msgLine.draw( self.win )
            self.set = True
        elif self.set:
            self.msgLine.undraw( )
            self.set = False

    def setColor( self, color ):
        "Change the text color"
        self.msgLine.setFill( color )
        #self.msgLine.setSize( 13 )
```

Comment: Could you show a minimal example directly?

Comment: I think if I did a minimal example I could get it to work.  It's tying together all the classes in the real application that's the difficulty.